# simple_form association not updating correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4.0.2, I have the following models/relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_account_assignments
  has_many :clients, -> { uniq }, through: :client_account_assignments
  ...
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_account_assignments
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :client_account_assignments
  ...
end
```

In the `edit.html.haml` view for users, I have the following form:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.association :clients, as: :select, collection: Client.all, value_method: :id, label_method: :name, include_blank: false, input_html: {data: {placeholder: "Choose..."}}
```

Adding clients to a user works as expected. However, deselecting one or more clients does not work correctly. For example:

1. `@user.id` => 1
2. `@user.clients.map(&:id)` => [70, 74, 76, 71, 72, 73, 75]
3. Navigate to `users/1/edit`
4. Deselect all clients except the client with id of 76.
5. Set breakpoint in `UsersController#update`.
6. Click "save".
7. `params[:user][:client_ids]` => ["", "76", "", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76"]

Why are all the previously-selected, now-unselected client ids being passed in the params?

Another example:

1. `@user.id` => 1
2. `@user.clients.map(&:id)` => [70]
3. Navigate to `users/1/edit`
4. Deselect all clients, except for the clients with ids of 71 and 72.
5. Click "save".
6. `params[:user][:client_ids]` => ["", "71", "72", "", "70"]

Again, why is the old client id (i.e., 70) still appearing in the params?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an easy answer: I was accidentally rendering the clients input more than once on the view, hence the old values being retained.